# How can I use seed data in swift's database without coding it?

Tags: swift, sqlite, core-data, ide, xcode6

Actually I found this [tutorial](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/02/25/using-swift-to-seed-a-core-data-database/) to get seed data in my database. But is there a build-in functionality in XCode where I can initially insert some entries? (Heidi, PhpMyAdmin or Sequel Pro)

Comment: Since sqlite is a single-file database, a common approach is to seed the data on a test machine, copy the file, and use it as your seed database for development and deployment.

Comment: Yeah, I see - I just found an article about Realm - might be a good approach as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, it is an editor for Code Data. You can review and edit entries.

https://github.com/ChristianKienle/Core-Data-Editor